Laravel livewire Dependent dropdown, send request as dropdown change
I am using Livewire and below is a dependent dropdown,
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-3 mb-md-5 mb-xl-1">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-2 gap-lg-3">
                <select class="form-select form-select-sm form-select-solid" wire:model.live="selectedSymbol"
                    id="symbol">
                    <option value="null">Select Symbol</option>
                    @foreach (\App\Models\NseFnoSymbol::distinct()->orderBy('id')->pluck('symbol') as $key => $value)
                        <option value="{{ $value }}" @if($selectedSymbol == $value) selected @endif>{{ $value }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

                <select class="form-select form-select-sm form-select-solid" wire:model.live="selectedExpiry"
                    wire:key="{{ $selectedSymbol }}" id="expiry">
                    <option value="null" disabled>Select Expiry</option>
                    @foreach (\App\Models\OptionExpiry::where('underlying_symbol', $selectedSymbol)->orderBy('expiry', 'asc')->distinct()->pluck('expiry') as $key => $value)
                        <option value="{{ $value }}" @if($selectedExpiry == $value) selected @endif>{{ $value }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>


Now dropdown works fine where select selectedSymbol it get its match selectedExpiry and it get selected in 2nd select option,
Now the question is, as I select selectedSymbol, it get selectedExpiry, it should fire a request to component to get new data as soon as selectedExpiry change,
Right now, I  get data only when I manually change selectedExpiry,
Desired behaviour is that on first instance, it should get data automatically, and then when use change selectedExpiry to other option, it get new data,
So how can I fire request to the component to send new data as soon as I change selectedSymbol at first time?

As I understood, you want these two dropdown, effect each other when one of them is chosen either symbol or expiry.
so you should use these functions in your class:
public function updatedSelectedExpiry(){
   // query to update you dropdown data
}

public function updatedSelectedSymbol(){
   // query to update you dropdown data
}

also set query to database in your class and then send them to blade so you can setthem from class.
